# Loading symbol file while linking

Tags: c, linker, arm, static-linking, symbols

I am trying to load a symbol file at the time of linking. I am providing the symbol.txt file along with other libraries that I link. These are the two things I tried.

- 1st, I provided the symbol file exactly as what was the output of arm-none-eabi-nm, but this returned with a syntax error on line 1 itself.
- 2nd, I changed the format a bit. I added `#< SYMDEFS >#` at the beginning of the file and made the changes to follow ARM's symdef file format. This gave me the error

> file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Does anyone have any experience in loading symbol files to the linker (arm-none-eabi-ld)? If yes, please help me figure out what I am missing above.

The first few lines of my symbol file is as follows:

> "#< SYMDEFS >#"   ;There is no " here, I used it to remove the markup
>   0x00000000 A __heap_size
>   0x00000000 R __vect_table
>   0x00000000 R __vector_table
>   0x00000074 A ___data_size

I know that this format works with armlink.

Comment: What do you mean by "symbol file"? Do you mean a *linker script*? The latter is a file for GNU ld in which normally symbols like `__heap_start` etl. al. are defined.

Comment: By symbol file I meant the output of arm-none-eabi-nm, not the linker script file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the GNU linker, just create a file that looks something like this and include it on the linker command line:

```
__intstk_top__ = __syspage_base__ + 0x2000;
__abortstk_top__ = __syspage_base__ + 0x3000;
__undefinedstk_top__ = __syspage_base__ + 0x4000;
__svcstk_top__ = __syspage_base__ + 0x6000;
__sysstk_top__ = __syspage_base__ + 0x8000;
__boot_pgd__ = __syspage_base__ + 0x8000;
__boot_pgd_physical__ = __syspage_physical_base__ + 0x8000;
__boot_pte0__ = __syspage_base__ + 0xC000;
__boot_pte0_physical__ = __syspage_physical_base__ + 0xC000;
__boot_pte1__ = __syspage_base__ + 0xD000;
__boot_pte1_physical__ = __syspage_physical_base__ + 0xD000;
__syspage_physical_base__ = 0x48000000;
__syspage_base__ = 0x80000000;
__syspage_size__ = 0xE000;
__device_base__ = 0xC0000000;
__user_limit__ = 0x7FFFFFFF;
__virtual_offset__ = 0x80000000 - __syspage_physical_base__;
__dev_offset__ = 0xC0000000;
__mmu_enabled__ = 1;
__kernel_base__ = __syspage_base__;
```

As you can see, the symbols can be defined as constants or with simple expressions that can be resolved at link time.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But, this did not work for me. I get the error "file format not recognized; treating as linker script" and "syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" at line:2. The modified symbol was like this: __heap_size = 0x00000000
__vect_table = 0x00000000
__vector_table = 0x00000000
___data_size = 0x00000074
__stack_size = 0x00000400

Comment: Are you putting the semicolon at the end of each line?

Comment: YES! it worked. I missed the semi-colons last time. Thanks Richard. Thanks to the power of vim I was quickly able to convert the standard symbol file to the format that you have mentioned. But this would mean I will need to have a post-build script to convert the arm-none-eabi-nm generated symbol file to this format. Would you know if there is an option/technique to load the utility generated symbol file itself at link time?

Comment: I have like more than 1000 symbols which needs to be imported. And because this is a utility generated file, I was thinking the same format should work for another utility (linker) under the same toolchain. Anyways,  thanks to you, I am glad that there at least one way to do this, with this toolchain.

Comment: Try this (replace "elk" with your object file name.

Comment: nm elk | sed -e "s/\([0-9a-f]*\) . \(.*\)/\2 = \1;/"

Comment: Oops! I forgot the "0x": nm elk | sed -e "s/\([0-9a-f]*\) . \(.*\)/\2 = 0x\1;/"

Comment: I am going to continue investigating into what could be a direct symbol loading method and wait for some more time before I settle on this as my final solution. I really do appreciate your help. Thanks.