# Code sharing between multiple independently compiled binaries/hex files

Tags: embedded, cortex-m

I'm looking for documentation/information on how to share information/code between multiple binaries compiled for a Cortex-m/0/4/7 architectures. The two binaries will be on the same chip and same architecture. They are flashed at different locations and sets the main stack pointer and resets the program counter so that one binary "jumps" to the other binary. I want to share code between these two binaries.

I've done a simple copy of an array of function pointers into a section defined in the linker script into RAM. Then read the RAM out in the other binary and cast it to an array then use the index to call functions in the other binary. This does work as a Proof-of-concept, but I think what I'm looking for is a bit more complex. As I want some way of describing compatibility between the two binaries. I want some what the functionality of shared libraries, but I'm unsure if I need position independent code.

As an example how the current copy process is done it is basically:

Source binary:

```
void copy_func()
{
   memncpy(array_of_function_pointers, fixed_size, address_custom_ram_section)
}
```

Binary which is jumped too from source binary:

```
array_fp_type get_funcs()
{
   memncpy(adress_custom_ram_section, fixed_size, array_of_fp)
   return array_of_fp;
}
```

Then I can use the `array_of_fp` to call into functions residing in the source binary from the jump binary.

So what I'm looking for is some resources or input for someone who have implemented a similar system. Like I would like to not have to have a custom RAM section where I'm copying the function pointers into.

I would be fine with having the compilation step of source binary outputting something which can be included into the compilation step of the jump binary. However it needs to be reproducible and recompiling the source binary shouldn't break the compatibility with the jump binary(even if it included a different file from what is now outputted) as long as you don't change the interface.

To clarify source binary shouldn't require any specific knowledge about the jump binary. The code should not reside in both binaries as this would defeat the purpose of this mechanism. The overall goal if this mechanism is a way to save space when creating multi-binary applications on cortex-m processors.

Any ideas or links to resources are welcome. If you have any more questions feel free to comment on the question and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: i'm not sure to understand, maybe you just want to compile the first program as a library and compile the second program including the first library ? Maybe explain why you want to do something like that so we can propose a solution

Comment: So I want source binary to run as a program( could be compiled as a library but I don't want to compile it into the jump binary) as a requirement is that both can be programmed separately just that they share some resources. So in a way that you have eg. a bootloader with a network stack( which is large) I want to share the network stack between the bootloader and the application using it. The bootloader has no knowledge of the application but the application has knowledge of the bootloader. Did that clear it up @Julien? So I don't want the code from source binary I want to use the functions.

Comment: this is no different really then how dlls or .so files work, and sounds like you are on the right track, you need some sort of data structure that identifies the functions or variables and their location in the compiled binary, pass that to the secondary program and it needs to use function pointers and such to connect to the other binary.  this is not a new problem been solved countless times and has nothing to do with mcus or the cortex-m...if I understand the question.

Comment: It is clear thank you. I will thing about a solution for your usage tonight. However, we could imagine an application + a bootloader  relying on same dynamic library.
App and boot rely on lib, app can be changed without impact on lib or boot.  Does this fit ?

Comment: Unlike a dll or so file, you may want or need to do more (or less) you may need to define on each side a known location where the table of pointers is so that re-compiling either side does not move them.   this is for runtime not for link time, if this is link time then just build the two binaries as one project (perhaps) and not need a table of pointers.

Comment: if the two binaries need to support being built at different times, then you may also want to version your structure so that one binary can examine the other and determine if it has the right structure and number of functions required and/or if a function changed how it works it may know it wont work with that other binary.

Comment: if you do it at link time then you are probably depending on the set, bootloader, libraries and app to all be built together.  If you want them separate then you need a runtime solution which is almost identical instead of at link time you get a table of addresses it is at run time that you get the table of addresses and instead of linking in known addresses from a link time table you at run time have to fill in a local table of pointers and/or use the indirect table.   runtime allows for boot, lib and app to be separately developed and flashed

Comment: @old_timer The last part sounds very much more into what I want. So from your response it seems that the best way to do this is through having a structure(struct) which some information about the version and a link table that gets populated by the bootloader/source binary with the functions from the library? However I will then not be able to updated the library in anyway like this right? As it's bounded to the source binary. Any idea how I could build the library separate so that I could update the content(functionality) of each function call of the library without breaking the source binary?

Comment: @Julien yeah this very much fit but there is no mechanism for shared libraries in arm-none-eabi-gcc as far as I know? So I guess it's sort of re-implementing a subset of a shared library for cortex-m processors. I don't' know if anyone have done this before because I couldn't find any information/ideas online about this hence why I asked this on stackoverflow. old_timer seems to have some idea on how this have been done.

Comment: when I say structure I dont directly mean a struct, using structs across compile domains in general is a bad ideal although this might be an exception.  It is a case of link time vs run time, the primary difference there is at link time you can if you choose have the linker resolve the addresses where at run time you have to do that in software somehow, although there are tricks to do this (point an array or struct to the other side).

Comment: its your code its a problem you have created for yourself rather than simply building the libraries in.  my point is this is not some new problem this problem was solved decades ago, long before this mcu could even be dreamed of existing.  so you get to design what your requirements are if you want the libraries to be able to be changed or functions re-designed,  how much forward or reverse compatibility there is, etc.  you need to go back and ask your self why do I want this separate library, boot separate from app is very typical.

Comment: you could spend the extra 10 cents and get the part with more flash and not have the resource problem that leads to a shared library solution.

Comment: or write tighter/cleaner code or use a different compiler, etc etc to reduce the binary size so the same part can do more (and not need a shared library solution).

Comment: The means to do this may be toolchain  specific, so you might want to specify the toolchain.  But essentially , you create a table of function pointers and arrange by whatever means your toolchain's supports to locate the table at a known address that is reserved for that purpose.  The second binary can then access that table to call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard for me to picture what you want to do, but if you're interested in having an application link against your bootloader/ROM, then see [Loading symbol file while linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850669/loading-symbol-file-while-linking) for a hint on what you could do.

Build your "source"(?) image, scrape its mapfile and make a symbol file, then use that when you link your "jump"(?) image.

This does mean you need to link your "jump" image against a specific version of your "source" image.

If you need them to be semi-version independent (i.e. you define a set of functions that get exported, but you can rebuild on either side), then you need to export function pointers at known locations in your "source" image and link against those function pointers in your "jump" image.  You can simplify the bookkeeping by making a structure of function pointers access the functions through that on either side.

For example:

shared_functions.h:

```
struct FunctionPointerTable
{
  void(*function1)(int);
  void(*function2)(char);
};

extern struct FunctionPointerTable sharedFunctions;
```

Source file in "source" image:

```
void function1Implementation(int a) 
{
    printf("You sent me an integer:  %d\r\n", a);

    function2Implementation((char)(a%256)) 
    sharedFunctions.function2((char)(a%256));
}

void function2Implementation(char b) 
{
    printf("You sent me an char:  %c\r\n", b);
}

struct FunctionPointerTable sharedFunctions = 
{
    function1Implementation,
    function2Implementation,
};
```

Source file in "jump" image:

```
#include "shared_functions.h"

sharedFunctions.function1(1024);
sharedFunctions.function2(100);
```

When you compile/link the "source", take its mapfile and extract the location of sharedFunctions and create a symbol file that is linked with the source the "jump" image.

Note:  the `printf`s (or anything directly called by the shared functions) would come from the "source" image (and not the "jump" image).

If you need them to come from the "jump" image (or be overridable) , then you need to access them through the same function pointer table, and the "jump" image needs to fix the function pointer table up with its version of the relevant function.  I updated the function1() to show this.  The direct call to function2 will always be the "source" version.   The shared function call version of it will go through the jump table and call the "source" version unless the "jump" image updates the function table to point to its implementation.

You CAN get away from the structure, but then you need to export the function pointers one by one (not a big problem), but you want to keep them in order and at a fixed location, which means explicitly putting them in the linker descriptor file, etc. etc.    I showed the structure method to distill it down to the easiest example.

As you can see, things get pretty hairy, and there is some penalty (calling through the function pointer is slower because you need to load up the address to jump to)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in comment, we could imagine an application and a bootloader relying on same dynamic library. So application and bootloader rely on library, application can be changed without impact on library or boot.

I did not find an easy way to do a shared library with arm-none-eabi-gcc. However 
[this document](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0242a/DAI0242A_dynamic_linking_with_rvct.pdf) gives some alternatives to shared libraries. I your case, I would recommand the jump table solution.

Write a library with the functions that need to be used in bootloader and in applicative.

**"library" code**

```
typedef void (*genericFunctionPointer)(void)

// use the linker script to set MySection at a known address
// I think this could be a structure like Russ Schultz solution but struct may or may not compile identically in lib and boot. However yes struct would be much easyer and avoiding many function pointer cast. 
const genericFunctionPointer FpointerArray[] __attribute__ ((section ("MySection")))=
{
     (genericFunctionPointer)lib_f1,
     (genericFunctionPointer)lib_f2,
}

void lib_f1(void)
{
     //some code
}

uint8_t lib_f2(uint8_t param)
{
     //some code
}
```

**applicative and/or bootloader code**

```
typedef void (*genericFunctionPointer)(void)

// Use the linker script to set MySection at same address as library was compiled
// in linker script also put this section as `NOLOAD` because it is init by library and not by our code
//volatile is needed here because you read in flash memory and compiler may initialyse usage of this array to NULL pointers
volatile const genericFunctionPointer FpointerArray[NB_F] __attribute__ ((section ("MySection")));

enum 
{
    lib_f1,
    lib_f2,
    NB_F,

}

int main(void)
{
    (correctCastF1)(FpointerArray[lib_f1])();
    uint8_t a = (correctCastF2)(FpointerArray[lib_f2])(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using linker sections. If you have your bootloader  source code in folder bootloader, you can use

```
SECTIONS
{
    .bootloader:
    {
        build_output/bootloader/*.o(.text)
    } >flash_region1

    .binary1: 
    {
        build_output/binary1/*.o(.text)
    } >flash_region2

    .binary2:
    {
        build_output/binary2/*.o(.text)
    } >flash_region3 
}
```